# having trouble writing to redis

Tags: python, kubernetes

i recently created a redis pod in kubernetes.  I am having trouble writing to the redis database.  I am getting an error `cant write to read only replica`

when i do `kubectl get pv` i see the following:

```
    local-pv1   1Gi        RWO            Retain           Bound    default/data-redis-0   local-storage            61m
local-pv2   1Gi        RWO            Retain           Bound    default/data-redis-1   local-storage            61m
local-pv3   2Gi        RWO            Retain           Bound    default/data-redis-2   local-storage            61m
```

`kubectl get pods`
and this leads to...

```
redis-0                                   1/1     Running   0             63m
redis-1                                   1/1     Running   0             63m
redis-2                                   1/1     Running   0             62m
redis-python-deployment-9cf76d5b5-hw2nf   1/1     Running   2 (28m ago)   28m
redis-python-deployment-9cf76d5b5-vf2f4   1/1     Running   1 (28m ago)   28m
redis-python-deployment-9cf76d5b5-wjxwn   1/1     Running   2 (28m ago)   28m
redis-python-deployment-9cf76d5b5-wlsjj   1/1     Running   0             28m
```

where redis-0 is the master and redis-1 and redis-2 are the slaves.

now im able to do this: `kubectl exec -it redis-0 sh` and then `redis-cli` and im able to perform the following: `xadd test * value 1`

Now I'm testing pushing data to this redis database.

```
import os
import random

import redis


def connect_to_redis():
    hostname = os.environ.get("REDISHOST", "localhost")
    password = os.environ["REDISPASSWORD"]
    port = os.environ["REDISPORT"]
    r = redis.Redis(hostname, port=int(port), password=password)
    return r


def send_data(redis_conn: redis.Redis, max_messages: int) -> None:
    count = 0
    while count < max_messages:
        try:
            data = {"price": random.random() * 100, "volume": random.random() * 10}
            resp = redis_conn.xadd(name="omega-orderbook", fields=data)
            print(resp)
            count += 1
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"error occured at {e}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    r = connect_to_redis()
    send_data(r, 10)
```

I've called the above python file and built it in teh following image: `docker build -t redis_practice`

Error im receiving is `You can't write against a read only replica.`

My redis headless service:

```
    # Headless service for stable DNS entries of StatefulSet members.
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: redis-service
spec:
  clusterIP: None
  ports:
    - port: 6379
      targetPort: 6379
      name: redis
  selector:
    app: redis
```

I do have a redis config that i have used from here: `https://gist.github.com/bharathirajatut/dcebde585eba5ac8b1398b8ed653d32d`

Is there anyway for me to refer to redis-0 in my python code?  currently i have it as:

```
redis.Redis('redis-service', host=6379, password=mysecretpass)
```

Thanks

edit: ok, i managed to connect to redis after getting the ip address of the master pod. is there another way to connect?

Comment: _after getting the ip address of the master pod_ - `redis-service.svc:6739` is what you want instead

Comment: u mean like 'redis-service.svc:6739'?

Comment: Sure, or you can set `REDISHOST=redis-service.svc` variable on your pod